# If I share an account, can I change that so they don't see my data, but they would still pay?

Tags: accounts, privacy

If I am under someone elses iTunes account because they pay, is there any way to make my own so they dont see everything on my iphone 4S

Answer (score 1):

You can use a different Apple ID for purchasing content and using Facetime, or Messages. You will need to set up your own Apple ID. [This is possible without having a credit card](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2534).

After this go to Settings > Facetime and sign out of the previous Apple ID, and sign into your new one. Do the same with iCloud - sign out with the previous Apple ID and sign into the new one. Now go to Messages > "Send & Receive at:" > Apple ID and do the same process.

After those three are set to the new Apple ID, go to Settings.app > iTunes & App Stores, and make sure the Apple ID at the top of the screen still says the **old** Apple ID.

Keep in mind that although this will keep your iCloud, Messages, Facetime, and such data separate, all receipts will go to the person who is paying for your purchases. They also can log in, at any time, and see what content you have purchased. The only way to avoid this would be for you to pay for your own purchases (you would need to change the "iTunes & App Stores" Apple ID).